# How can I improve debugging functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've improved my code a bit, moving the timer to app settings and using %% variable in the timer definition of the function.

I have a function that I want to run every night at 1am. But for debugging I really want it to fire as fast as possible after startup. I solved this by setting the pattern to `5 * * * * *` timer in app setting locally, and `0 0 1 * * *` in the app config in Azure.

But I don't want to have it actually run every 5 sec, I just want it to fire as fast as possible while debugging. So I've added a counter variable. Enabling only the first run to move forward:

```
        private static int count = 0;

        [Disable]
        [FunctionName("FetchProjects")]
        async public static void Run([TimerTrigger("%FetchProjectsTimer%")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
        {
#if DEBUG
            if (count != 0) return;
            count++;
#endif
```

How can I improve this if possible? The count isn't thread safe for one, and I want to remove the #if DEBUG check if possible

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. You just want to test the logic of your time trigger? What about unit test it (just the logic).

I usually leave my Azure functions as thin as possible and unit test the business logic. Here's how you can do it:

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

        FooService.DoFoo();
    }

    [FunctionName("Function2")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        FooService.DoFoo();

        return new OkObjectResult($"Success");
    }
}

//extracted logic which I will be tested by Nunit
public static class FooService
{
    public static void DoFoo()
    {
        //some logic in here
    }
}
```